# BigQuery SQL for JSON field returns no data

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery, unnest

Yet again I find myself flumoxed with my SQL of JSON field in bigquery.

This is the contents of a field called json_data - https://storage.googleapis.com/greyrock_storage/misc/freepik.json

The record has an id of 1675816490

This is my SQL:

```
    SELECT
       ##JSON_EXTRACT(json_data, '$data.resources.boost.url_source') AS url_source,
      JSON_VALUE(boost, "$.url_source") AS url_source,


    FROM  `my database` ,

      UNNEST(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(json_data.data)) AS data,
      UNNEST(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(data.resources)) AS resources,
      UNNEST(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(resources.boost)) AS boost

   WHERE
   id = 1675816490
```

I expected to see a list of all the values in the record for data.resources.boost.url_source BUT it returns 'There is no data to display.'

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(boosts.url_source) AS url_source
FROM `my database` AS a
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(a.json_data.data.resources.boost)) AS boosts
```